# How to test negative if.bind with aurelia-testing

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to write a test for an Aurelia component that displays nothing until some data is loaded. It looks something like this:

```
class MyComponent {
    @bindable
    someId;

    myData = undefined;

    someIdChanged() {
        externalService.someLookup(someId).then(data => this.myData = data);
    }
}
```

with template

```
<template>
    <div if.bind="myData !== undefined" class="special-styling">
        ${myData.title}
    </div>
</template>
```

It's easy to write a test for the scenario where `myData` is eventually loaded: I can call `ComponentTester.waitForElement('.special-styling')` or some such. But now I want to write a test where loading the data fails immediately, and I assert that the `div` should be absent. However, I'm not sure how to time it: if I check immediately whether the `div` is present, than that could be because the component works correctly and the `div` isn't shown, but it could also be that the component is faulty but hasn't finished rendering yet.

For now, as a workaround, I'm doing something like `setTimeout(() => expect(div).not.to.exist, 50)`, but ideally I'd like to have some signal that the request is done, Aurelia has finished updated, and then assert the absence of the `div`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/aurelia/testing/issues/36) prompted me to think about using the `TaskQueue` to time this. I'm still looking into that.

Comment: Following [this example](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/test/shared.ts) it turns out that for simple tests, it's enough to wait one cycle (e.g. `await new Promise(setTimeout)`). However, I'm not sure if this is guaranteed to work for every case.

Comment: Subscribing.. please post your own answer, when you figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You would normally put your check behind a `queueMicroTask()` during the `attached()` phase. That's really all the "delay" you need to ensure aurelia finished rendering. See this [somewhat related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596232/custom-attribute-attached-event-too-early/49165979#49165979) I gave earlier for a detail on why.

However `aurelia-testing` has slightly different timings when it comes to rendering and such. It actually uses `setTimeout()` on places where the actual framework doesn't. This is to account for inevitable delays incurred by testing frameworks. So you'll want to keep your `setTimeout()` or alternatively you could use `queueTask()` (which uses `setTimeout()` internally) to achieve a similar effect.

If you really want to be sure, just do this:

`ComponentTester.waitForElement('.special-styling', { interval: 5, timeout: 15 })`

With that said your test is kind of unnecessary. All you'd need to verify is that the expression passed to `if.bind` actually evaluates to false if your data fails to load. What you're doing now is testing whether `if.bind` works as well, and you really don't want/need to test the Aurelia framework itself :)

Comment: I'd make the subtle distinction that in this test I'm not checking whether `if.bind` works, but rather that I didn't screw up the expression that I passed to `if.bind` in my template ;) I could do `expect(component.viewModel.data).to.be.undefined`, but that doesn't prevent me from using a wrong expression in my template. I'm trying to treat the view / viewmodel combination as a black box in my tests as much as possible.

Comment: Fair point. If you're all for encapsulation though, why not add a boolean property `displayMyData` to your view model and directly pass that to `if.bind`, so your view only deals with the display part and your view model deals with "what to display". Then add `@observable()` to the `myData` property and in your `myDataChanged(newValue, oldValue)` you set the `displayMyData` to true/false depending on whether `newValue` is defined. Then you just test the `displayMyData` property. Simplifies your test, simplifies your view?

Comment: If my goal was to encapsulate my view from the view model, so that I could test the VM separately, that would be precisely the way to go about it, I agree. But my mental model has always been to regard the two together as an encapsulated unit, communicating with the outside world through bindings and shared services / state management , but not hiding state from each other. And they communicate with the user through UI, which is what I want to verify in my test. Not necessarily the best model perhaps, but it works pretty well for me.

Comment: I respect your model and I don't think it's wrong per se. You are however constraining yourself to merely a subset of what Aurelia can do when you think about it. Built-in features like `router-view layout.bind`, `useView()`, `viewStrategy`, `compose` and numerous others all revolve around being able to mix and match different views and VMs to further improve code reusability. I personally like to have my VMs do all the computational stuff and keep the views simple and clean. A big reason for that being it also improves the testability. Testing html will always be a bit tricky.. :)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for adding your thoughts.

Comment: @FredKleuver There are bunch of trivial computations which are clearer and more  readable if used directly in the view, instead of encapsulating all those in VM adding vague name to each of them. `if.bind="myData !== undefined"` vs `displayMyData` is good example of such trivial computation.